What's the best/right way to implement retry logic for sending Solana Transactions?
I've been trying to put together a trading bot that will execute Solana Transactions based on certain conditions. I've been using python solana and solders, and piecing code together. I'm an okay developer but not super confident with the different Solana transaction bits. Anyways I have the code below that seems to work okay so far to execute swaps however it doesn't always work (I'm assuming due to the rpc I'm using which is just the normal Mainnet one from Solana (thinking of switching to Helius but was running into some errors which I'll need to debug). Could anyone help suggest how best I could implement logic to confirm a transaction and retry without obviously repeating a transaction.
def execute_swap(private_key: Keypair, wallet_address: str, input_mint: str, output_mint: str, amount: int, solana_rpc_url: str):
    """
    Executes a swap transaction on the Solana blockchain using Jupiter API.

    Args:
        private_key (str): Base58-encoded private key of the wallet.
        wallet_address (str): Public address of the wallet.
        input_mint (str): Mint address of the input token (e.g., SOL).
        output_mint (str): Mint address of the output token (e.g., USDC).
        amount (int): Amount to swap (in lamports for SOL).
        solana_rpc_url (str): Solana RPC endpoint.

    Returns:
        str: Transaction ID of the executed swap.
    """
    # Jupiter API endpoints
    quote_url = f"https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint={input_mint}&outputMint={output_mint}&amount={amount}"
    swap_url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap"

    try:
        logging.info("Starting swap execution process...")

        # Initialize keypair and client
        logging.info("Initializing Solana client...")
        client = Client(endpoint=solana_rpc_url)
        # Step 1: Fetch the quote response
        logging.info(f"Fetching quote from Jupiter API: {quote_url}")
        quote_response = requests.get(url=quote_url).json()
        logging.info(f"Quote response: {quote_response}")

        # Step 2: Prepare the swap payload
        payload = {
            "quoteResponse": quote_response,
            "userPublicKey": wallet_address,
            "wrapUnwrapSOL": True,
            "prioritizationFeeLamports": "auto",
            "dynamicSlippage": { "maxBps": 300}
        }
        logging.info(f"Prepared payload for swap: {payload}")

        # Step 3: Fetch the swap transaction route
        logging.info(f"Sending payload to fetch swap transaction: {swap_url}")
        swap_response = requests.post(url=swap_url, json=payload).json()
        logging.info(f"Swap response: {swap_response}")

        swap_transaction = swap_response.get('swapTransaction')
        if not swap_transaction:
            logging.error("No swap transaction found in response!")
            raise ValueError(f"Error fetching swap transaction: {swap_response}")

        logging.info("Successfully fetched swap transaction.")

       # Step 4: Decode and sign the transaction
        logging.info("Decoding and signing the transaction...")
        raw_transaction = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_transaction))
        signature = private_key.sign_message(to_bytes_versioned(raw_transaction.message))  # Sign the serialized message
        signed_txn = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_transaction.message, [signature])  # Populate the transaction
        logging.info("Transaction signed successfully.")

        # Step 5: Send the signed transaction
        logging.info("Sending signed transaction to Solana network...")
        opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=False, preflight_commitment=Processed)
        result = client.send_raw_transaction(txn=bytes(signed_txn), opts=opts) #UPDATE TO STAKED RPC
        logging.info(f"Transaction sent successfully. Response: {result}")

        # Step 6: Extract and return the transaction ID
        transaction_id = json.loads(result.to_json())['result']
        logging.info(f"Transaction ID: {transaction_id}")
    
        # Step 7: Confirm transaction status
        logging.info("Checking transaction confirmation status...")
        confirmation = client.confirm_transaction(signature, commitment="confirmed")
        if confirmation['value'] and confirmation['value']['err'] is None:
            logging.info(f"Transaction confirmed: {transaction_id}")
            return f"Transaction confirmed: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/{transaction_id}"
        else:
            logging.warning(f"Transaction not confirmed: {transaction_id}")
            return f"Transaction not confirmed. Check: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/{transaction_id}"

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error executing swap: {e}")
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error executing swap: {e}")

